# leaflet layer control checkbox options min/max

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers

I have a straight forward leaflet map that is on a webpage. I am using the angular-leaflet-directive and all works as expected except for the layer control box.

When only one baselayer is specified I get no control object (expected behavior).
When two or more baselayers are specified I get the control layer with toggleable options  (expected behavior).
However, I also get a min and a max checkbox that I did not configure, create or in any other way define.

I cannot find any reference to these in the directive, the leaflet library, any plugins or even find a mention of it when Googling.

[image]

Does anyone know what this is and where it is coming from??

The map otherwise works exactly as expected (with legends, markers, etc.).

Here is the layer object source:

```
angular.extend($scope, {

      pageClass: 'maps-data',

      texas: {
        lat: 31.555502,
        lng: -98.959761,
        zoom: 5
      },

      defaults: {
        // tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        // maxZoom: 14,
        path: {
          weight: 10,
          color: '#800000',
          opacity: 1
        }
      },

      legend: {
        position: 'bottomleft',
        colors: [ '#904', '#ff0000', '#28c9ff', '#0000ff', '#ecf386' ],
        labels: [ 'Texas', 'Drainage', 'Recharge', 'Artesian', 'Authority Zone' ]
      },

      markers: {
        eaa: {
          lat: 29.555502,
          lng: -98.959761,
          message: "Edwards Aquifer Authority",
          focus: false, // true means the message box will be visible initially.
          draggable: false
        }
      },

      layers: {

        baselayers: {
          mqosm: {
            name: 'Map Quest OSM',
            url: 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
            type: 'xyz',
            layerOptions: {
              subdomains: [ 'otile1', 'otile2', 'otile3', 'otile4' ],
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
              continuousWorld: true
            }
          },
          osm: {
            name: 'Open Street Map',
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz',
            layerOptions: {
              subdomains: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
              continuousWorld: true
            }
          },
          landscape: {
            name: 'Landscape',
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz',
            layerOptions: {
              subdomains: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.thunderforest.com/terms"">ThunderForest</a> terms',
              continuousWorld: true
            }
          },
          bwmap: {
            name: 'B&W Map',
            url: 'http://{s}.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz',
            layerOptions: {
              subdomains: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
              continuousWorld: true
            }
          }
        },

        overlays: {
          majorAquifers: {
            name:'Texas Major Aquifers',
            type:'geoJSON',
            url:'../../data/geojson/NEW_major_aquifers_dd_reduced100.geo.json',
            layerOptions: {
              style: {
                'color': '#000',
                'fillColor': '#09c',
                'weight': 1.0,
                'opacity': 0.7,
                'fillOpacity': 0.7
              }
            },
            pluginOptions: {
              cliptiles: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: can you paste source code or the address of the webmap?

Comment: @butcher, see my edit. Pretty straight forward baselayers (all loading and working fine). I'm so baffled...